# How to add condition in joining when the target table is associated with 3rd table also

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Let's say we have
table A,
table B,
table C,

a is associated with b by id
a is associated with c by key
b is associated with c by mobile

now i am querying in sequelize

```
A.findAll({
   include: [
     {
       model: b
       include: [
          {
            model: c
          }
       ]
     }
   ]
})
```

now how can i include this condition on joining B and C in ON (B.mobile = C.mobile and C.key = A.key)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on` option of the `include` option like this:

```js
const items = A.findAll({
  include: [
    model: B,
    include: [{
      model: C,
      on: {
        mobile: Sequelize.col('B.mobile'),
        key: Sequelize.col('A.key'),
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

If such `ON` wouldn't work in MySQL then you can try to move `key: Sequelize.col('A.key')` to the main `where` option:

```js
const items = A.findAll({
  where: {
    key: Sequelize.col('C.key')
  },
  include: [
    model: B,
    include: [{
      model: C,
      on: {
        mobile: Sequelize.col('B.mobile'),
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```